# Can't acess information on the useSelector by redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I can access the information that is in the redux by console.log ... but when i try to access certain part of this information i get some type error.

```
const profile = useSelector(state => state);

console.log(profile);  // Work's and print the info
console.log(profile.auth.token); // Does not work
```

> TypeScript error in /src/components/Header/index.tsx(17,24):
>   Object is of type 'unknown'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding type to profile i.e

```
Const profile:any = useSelector(state=>state)
```

Or

```
Const profile:object<any> = useSelector(state=>state)
```

In typescript if you are trying to access any of these properties of an object, it must have a type.